# How to make an interpreter than can serialize all data including lambda functions?

Tags: lambda, lisp, interpreter

In lisp/scheme the functions WRITE and READ can output any data in the language and read it back in except for lambdas/closures.

An example of what I'd like to be able to do is:

```
(define f (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
(write (f 2))
```

should output something which can be read back in and used like this

```
((read) 7)
```

to get the result `9`.

How  would this be implemented? Are there any textbooks or documents that explain the details of making an interpreter with this feature? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact Lisp systems *can't* read and write arbitrary objects: only sufficiently simple ones.  As an example from Common Lisp, given

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((x :reader foo-x :initarg :x)))
```

Then:

```
> (make-instance 'foo :x 2)
#<foo 40200A9813>
```

And that's not something that can be read.

### The general problem

For a Lisp / Scheme to be able to write ('stash' below) general objects to files and read ('unstash' below) them from files you need, at least, enough introspection to be able to know what the parts of the object are.  For it to be able to stash & unstash objects reliably you also need to be able to know what the object depends on.  That's simply not present for functions or closures in any portable way, and the dependency problem is severe.

As an example, consider this (in Scheme now):

```
(define y 3)

(define (bar x)
  (+ x y))

(define (foo x)
  (cons (bar x) x))
```

What should happen if I say `(stash foo "/tmp/foo")`?

- As a bare minimum, the system must be able to understand `foo` well enough to stash it in some form that it can be reconstructed when loaded.
- But `foo` has dependencies: it depends on `bar` and `bar` in turn depends on `y`, as well as dependencies on `cons` and `+` which probably can be ignored (but only probably).  Do I need to stash those things as well?  Because if I don't then trying to unstash the definition back from the file I stashed to is going to fail horribly if I do it in a context where these things don't have definitions.

So stashing general objects, and in particular functions, to external storage, and doing it correctly is an enormous problem.  In particular I think it's not even a *well-defined* problem.  For instance, in many implementations, things like `+` or `cons` may not actually refer to what you assume, and implicit operations like function application may not do what you think: should *that* be saved with object you are saving?

Solving these problems *correctly* and *generally* is very hard, and in fact the problems are not well-posed enough that there even is a well-defined solution.

### Specific problems

However, this doesn't mean that the problem is not solvable for specific cases where you simply don't care about some or all of these problems.

Here is some code in Racket which deals with some simple cases, for instance.

**Notes:**

- this code is *unsafe*: it calls `load` which is tantamount to calling `eval` and has all the dangers of that;
- the definition of `define/stashing` probably misses some important cases in the syntax of `define`;
- `define/stashing` won't work properly except at toplevel (because lexical environments are simply not dealt with at all);
- there is no attempt to deal with dependencies or any of the hard problems;
- a special case of the above is that recursive functions won't work unless they are written carefully;
- I haven't checked whether this is portable Scheme but probably not.

In general this is just a hacky demonstration that it is quite easy to deal with some special cases which might be interesting in practice.

```
(define definition-map (make-hasheqv))

(define (save-definition! thing source-form)
  (hash-set! definition-map thing source-form)
  thing)

(define (get-definition thing)
  (hash-ref definition-map thing))

(define (clear-definitions!)
  (hash-clear! definition-map))

(define-syntax define/stashing
  ;; This is probably missing cases
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (name) form ...)
     (define name (save-definition! (lambda () form ...)
                                   '(lambda () form ...)))]
    [(_ (name arg ...) form ...)
     (define name (save-definition!
                   (lambda (arg ...) form ...)
                   '(lambda (arg ...) form ...)))]
    [(_ (name arg ... . rest) form ...)
     (define name (save-definition!
                   (lambda (arg ... . rest) form ...)
                   '(lambda (arg ... . rest) form ...)))]
    [(_ name value)
     (define name (save-definition! value 'value))]))

(define (stash thing file)
  (call-with-output-file
      file
    (λ (o)
      (write (get-definition thing) o)
      thing)
    #:mode 'text
    #:exists 'truncate/replace))

(define (unstash file)
  (load file))
```

To use this you need to use `define/stashing` instead of `define` (a module could make `define` *be* `define/stashing` of course) and then `stash` & `unstash`:

```
> (define/stashing (cons-1 x) (cons x 1))
> (stash cons-1 "/tmp/x")
#<procedure>
> (cons-1 2)
'(2 . 1)
> ((unstash "/tmp/x") 2)
'(2 . 1)
```

If you want to stash recursive functions you need to write them with local definitions:

```
(define/stashing (fact n)
  (let floop ([m 1] [t 1])
    (if (= m n)
        (* t m)
        (floop (+ m 1) (* t m)))))
```

will work, while

```
(define/stashing (fact n)
  (if (= n 1)
      n
      (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

won't, although it will *appear* to work if you `unstash` it into the same REPL that you defined it in.